# Aggregate multiple dictionary without overriding data

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I am giving sample dictionary and expected dictionary.

d1={'AA':['1','2','3'],'BB':['11','22'],'CC':['44','55','66','77']}
d2={'AA':['ab','bc','3'],'BB':['11','bb','12'],'DD':['cc','56','65']}

OUtput expecting:-
d3={'AA':['1','2','3','ab','bc'],'BB':['11','22','bb','12'],'CC':['44','55','66','77'],
'DD':['cc','56','65',] }
and last i want to print it in csv file as:- col1    col2
AA       1
AA       2
AA       3
and so on....

I tried using dataframe but dataframe formed is of unequal length of array.

Comment: Where is your problem? The writing to a csv file or the code itself? What have you tried so far?

Comment: my approach of using update() doesn't work..so plz help in joining dictionary and forming dataframe from resulting dict.